# How are the Apache Solr search results sequenced?

Tags: apache, drupal-6, solr

I have [Apache Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) 6.x-1.0-rc3 module installed in my site and it works fine. I wanted to know how are the Apache Solr search results sequenced. I have tried a few things and have concluded that it's not alphabetical or according to the recently updated node.

How are the search results sequenced? I mean in what order or logic.

Comment: by "sequenced" you mean "ordered"? Probably they're ordered by best match.

Comment: By default results in Solr are ordered by Solr`s defined score, which it has determined from each document.

Answer (score 2):

Basically,  it's scored based on the strength of the match with a few boosting factors added.  There's a great breakdown on the algorithm here:
http://www.supermind.org/blog/378/lucene-scoring-for-dummies

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Solr results are sorted by relevance score by default. The fields within a single result should be in the same order in which they were committed (at least within multi-valued fields...should be true for all fields, though), so you should be able to preserve some field sorting that you might do in the processing script. If you just show all results, I think the results are ordered by the order they were added to the index.

Comment: Hey Hi all and thank you for ur answers. Appreciated!!!
I did some studying on as to how can we organise search results. Here is what we can do. We can enable block called Apache Solr Core: Sorting for Apache solr which will give you different sorting options. 
Now it has different options like Sort by
1) Relevance 2)Type 3) Author 4) title and 5) Date.
I wanted to know what do all these options mean
Please Help!!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Solr Wiki page (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters) says the default sort order is `score desc`.